# How compile all scss files to desired path

Tags: css, sass, path

In my project I have 2 directory called `sass` and `css` like this:

```
project/
├── css/
│   └── ...
├── sass/
│   └──main/
│      └── main.scss
│   └──global/
│      ├── _fonts.scss
│      ├── _custom.scss
│      └── global.scss
```

Now, when I run `sass --watch sass:css`, it compile as well all scss files to css file in corresponding directory like: **sass/main/main.scss** to **css/main/main.css**

But I want **watch** all scss files in sass directory to my desired path like `css/main.css`.

I do not need to create a similar directory in css folder and my ultimate goal is to have a single file called `main.css` in `css` directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By beginning a file-name with an underscore (e.g. `_variables.scss`) it becomes a *[partial](https://sass-lang.com/guide)*. These files will not be compiled on their own, but need to be `@imported` into a file fist (which is not a partial) to only then be compiled as *one* file. You can kinda imagine this as an "injection".

---

The folder structure might then be similar to this.

```
/sass
+-/abstracts
|  +- _variables
|  +- _mixins
|     ...
+-/components
|  +- _forms
|    ...
main.scss
```

And your `main.scss` might only consist of `@imports`

```
// Abstracts
@import 'abstracts/variables';

...

// Components
@import 'components/forms';

...
```

**Note**: as well as the `.scss` the `_` can be ignored when importing a file.